# Worldserver crashes when applying updates

Tags: azerothcore

```
AzerothCore rev. 017772043d9d 2022-01-05 23:22:43 +0000 (master branch) (Win64, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (worldserver-daemon)
<Ctrl-C> to stop.

   █████╗ ███████╗███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗██╗  ██╗
  ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║
  ███████║  ███╔╝ █████╗  ██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║   ███████║
  ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║   ██╔══██║
  ██║  ██║███████╗███████╗██║  ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║   ██║  ██║
  ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝
                                 ██████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗
                                ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
                                ╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
                                 ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

     AzerothCore 3.3.5a  -  www.azerothcore.org

> Using configuration file       configs/worldserver.conf
> Using SSL version:             OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021 (library: OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021)
> Using Boost version:           1.74.0
 
Process priority class set to HIGH
Initializing Scripts...
> Loading C++ scripts
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_auth'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_auth' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_characters'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 2.
DatabasePool 'acore_characters' opened successfully. 3 total connections running.
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_world'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_world' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.
 
Updating Auth database...
>> Auth database is up-to-date! Containing 2 new and 26 archived updates.
 
Updating Character database...
>> Character database is up-to-date! Containing 4 new and 40 archived updates.
 
Updating World database...
>> Applying update "2021_12_29_01.sql" '4170551'...
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.♪◙ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 4: MySQL server has gone away♪◙
Applying of file 'C:/azerothcore/data/sql/updates/db_world/2021_12_29_01.sql' to database 'acore_world' failed! If you are a user, please pull the latest revision from the repository. Also make sure you have not applied any of the databases with your sql client. You cannot use auto-update system and import sql files from AzerothCore repository with your sql client. If you are a developer, please fix your sql query.
Could not update the World database, see log for details.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_world'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_world' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_world' closed.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_characters'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' closed.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_auth'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_auth' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_auth' closed.
```

Comment: The real problem is `ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 4: MySQL server has gone away` and I suggest to google it because you probably have to change some MySQL configuration to get it working, it's quite a common error.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Common Errors page](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/common-errors) on the [AzerothCore Wiki](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/home):

> This is most likely due to your MySQL server's `max_allowed_packet`
> setting is too low. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-6323/gicxk/index.html) or run the command `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;` in your SQL client (HeidiSQL, SQLyog,
> etc.) to update your `max_allowed_packet`.